# Prove that the image of an invariant subspace under a morphism of representations is an invariant subspace.

Tags: category-theory, representation-theory, invariant-theory, invariant-subspace

Prove that the image of an invariant subspace under a morphism of representations is an invariant subspace. Could anyone give me a hint on how to solve this Please?

**Knowing the following:**

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

And Remark 2 is given below:

[image]

**MY THOUGHT:**

I have proved this problem before:

[image]

And I think it will be helpful here but I do not know how .... could anyone help me please?

Comment: Okay I will edit my question to include my thought @Max

Comment: @Max I have edited my question.

Comment: Please do [not use pictures for critical portions](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/290189) of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not viewable to some, such as those who use screen readers. [Scanned pages from books are *forbidden* on SE network](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/155600/259305). Questions should contain sufficient context so that it is [answerable with the text alone](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1807/290189).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have $\sigma \colon V_1 \to V_2$ such that $\sigma T_1(g) = T_2(g)\sigma$ for all $g\in G$. Let $U\subset V_1$ be an invariant subspace. We want see what happens to $\sigma(U)$.

Let $ v = \sigma(w) \in \sigma(U)$ for some $w\in V_1$ then 
$$
T_2(g)v = T_2(g)\sigma(w) = \sigma (T_1(g)w ) \in \sigma(U)
$$
since $T_1(g)w\in U$.